# Which of these is grammatically correct? "lay foundation to" or "lay foundation for"?

Tags: grammaticality

The last line in one my admission letters is "...and also to lay foundation to my long term career goals."

Is it more correct for me to write "lay foundation for" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is ["to lay the foundation for"](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/british/lay-the-foundations-of-for).